# How to use Allen NLP interpret on custom models

Tags: heatmap, allennlp

I wish to use Allen NLP Interpret for integrated visualization and Saliency mapping.on custom transformer model, can you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 5):

It can be done by having AllenNLP wrappers around your custom model. The interpret modules require a Predictor object, so you can write your own, or use an existing one.

Here's an example for a classification model:

```
from allennlp.data.vocabulary import Vocabulary

from allennlp.predictors.text_classifier import TextClassifierPredictor
from allennlp.data.dataset_readers import TextClassificationJsonReader

import torch
  
class ModelWrapper(Model):
    def __init__(self, vocab, your_model):
        super().__init__(vocab)
        self.your_model = your_model
        self.logits_to_probs = torch.nn.Softmax()
        self.loss = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    def forward(self, tokens, label=None):
        if label is not None:
            outputs = self.your_model(tokens, label=label)
        else:
            outputs = self.your_model(tokens)
        probs = self.logits_to_probs(outputs["logits"])
        if label is not None:
            loss = self.loss(outputs["logits"], label)
            outputs["loss"] = loss
        outputs["probs"] = probs
        return outputs
```

Your custom transformer model may not have an identifiable `TextFieldEmbedder`. This is the initial embedding layer of your model, against which gradients are calculated for the saliency interpreters. These can be specified by overriding the following methods in the Predictor.

```
class PredictorWrapper(TextClassifierPredictor):
    def get_interpretable_layer(self):
        return self._model.model.bert.embeddings.word_embeddings # This is the initial layer for huggingface's `bert-base-uncased`; change according to your custom model.

    def get_interpretable_text_field_embedder(self):
        return self._model.model.bert.embeddings.word_embeddings
    
predictor = PredictorWrapper(model=ModelWrapper(vocab, your_model),
                             dataset_reader=TextClassificationJsonReader())
```

Now you have an AllenNLP predictor, which can be used with the interpret module as follows:

```
from allennlp.interpret.saliency_interpreters import SimpleGradient
interpreter = SimpleGradient(predictor)
interpreter.saliency_interpret_from_json({"sentence": "This is a good movie."})
```

This should give you the gradients with respect to each input token.