# Loading HF transformers BERT model into Allen NLP interpret module

Tags: huggingface-transformers, allennlp

I am looking for a way to utilise Allen NLP interpret module with HuggingFace transformers BERT model of architecture BertForSequenceClassification (trained with pytorch).

I've found an Allen NLP guide regarding common usage of interpret module with models that are structurized differently than my model.

Could someone help me and describe what could be the proper approach at converting BertForSequenceClassification model that could be loaded into `Predictor` object?

Guide sample found at https://guide.allennlp.org/interpret#3 :

```
from allennlp.interpret.saliency_interpreters import SimpleGradient
from allennlp.predictors import Predictor

inputs = {"sentence": "a very well-made, funny and entertaining picture."}
archive = (
    "https://storage.googleapis.com/allennlp-public-models/"
    "basic_stanford_sentiment_treebank-2020.06.09.tar.gz"
)
predictor = Predictor.from_path(archive)
interpreter = SimpleGradient(predictor)
interpretation = interpreter.saliency_interpret_from_json(inputs)

print(interpretation)
```

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806905/how-to-use-allen-nlp-interpret-on-custom-models/65951248#65951248?

Comment: Yes, I have, yet I failed to instantiate `predictor` object/use `ModelWrapper` properly.