# How to use AllenNLP interpret on finetuned t5 model

Tags: huggingface-transformers, allennlp

I have trained a T5 model on a specific dataset for the purpose of keyword extraction. I wish to use Allen NLP Interpret to know various saliency mappings for the inputs given to my model. Where do I make changes such that I can use the package.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The AllenNLP guide has a chapter on interpreting models: https://guide.allennlp.org/interpret

Also, for custom models, here's an example: [How to use Allen NLP interpret on custom models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806905/how-to-use-allen-nlp-interpret-on-custom-models/65951248#65951248)