# Adding a pretrained model outside of AllenNLP to the AllenNLP demo

Tags: pytorch, demo, allennlp, interpretation, huggingface

I am working on the interpretability of models. I want to use AllenAI demo to check the saliency maps and adversarial attack methods (implemented in this demo) on some other models. I use the tutorial [here](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-demo#contributing-a-new-allennlp-model-to-the-demo) and run the demo on my local machine. Now that I want to load my pretrained model which is from the huggingface ("cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment-latest" using this [code](https://huggingface.co/cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment-latest)) I don't know how to add the model to the demo. I checked the tutorial [here](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-demo/blob/SweepNotBrokenDammit/doc/AddingModelEndpoint.md) but this guide only is based on the models implemented in AllenNLP.

These are the changes on the new directory(roberta_sentiment_twitter) I made in allennlp_demo file but for sure it is not true since the main implementation only uses the models implemented in allennlp.

```
#in model.json
{
"id": "roberta-sentiment-twitter",
"pretrained_model_id": "cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment-latest"
}

#in api.py
import os
from allennlp_demo.common import config, http
from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoConfig

if __name__ == "__main__":

    MODEL = f"cardiffnlp/twitter-roberta-base-sentiment-latest"
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODEL)
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(MODEL)
    # model = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL)

    endpoint = AutoModelForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(MODEL)
    endpoint.run()


#in test_api.py
from allennlp_demo.common.testing import ModelEndpointTestCase
from allennlp_demo.roberta_sentiment_twitter.api import RobertaSentimentAnalysisModelEndpoint


class TestRobertaSentimentTwitterModelEndpoint(ModelEndpointTestCase):
    endpoint = RobertaSentimentAnalysisModelEndpoint()
    predict_input = {"sentence": "a very well-made, funny and entertaining picture."}
```

Is there any straightforward ways to load my models in the AllenNLP demo?
Also in the future I want to add some other interpretability method to this demo. Is there any tutorial for that too?

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply interested in getting the output from various saliency interpreters, this [guide chapter](https://guide.allennlp.org/interpret) explains how to use the API (you will not need the front-end demo code for this). If you want to apply the interpreters to your custom models, you may also find
[How to use Allen NLP interpret on custom models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65806905/how-to-use-allen-nlp-interpret-on-custom-models/65951248#65951248) helpful.

For adding your custom interpreters, you can install allennlp from source and add your methods in allennlp/interpret. Feel free to make a PR at https://github.com/allenai/allennlp too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want local and global interpretability that extracts what your model has learned directly from the model itself, try Leap Labs (https://www.leap-labs.com/). They have a waitlist for their new interpretability tools coming out in the next few weeks including feature visualization and saliency mapping using hierarchical perturbation.